# How to replace an object with a pattern

Tags: photoshop

I would like to remove the light blue pet box. Possibly replacing it with the floor texutre. What is the best way of doing it?

[image]

Comment: Define "the best way". The easiest? The fastest? The most natural result?

Comment: Did you try anything yet and why did that fail ?

Comment: Well, the point is I don't know how to do it. I can do simple things using clone or heal tool. But in this case there is very little texture compared to the part I want to remove

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not a photographic question, but I'd suggest you consider not replacing the background.  It's probably not really interfering with the photo in it's full context, and it's common for photographers to worry about details that the people viewing the image will not even notice.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question as asked, you could probably use an HSL/HSV tool to desaturate and dim the aqua/blue pet carrier and it would not be near as distracting. For more on using HSL/HSV tools, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/83888/15871). Instead of removing all but one color, you would only remove one (or two) colors and leave the rest. It's very easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What tools do you have available?

In PS you can make a composite by taking a picture of the scene from the same angle and use that 'clean' image to replace the area in question with the floor from your second shot.  I am pretty sure you can also accomplish this in Gimp.

- Create a mask of the floor and box.
- Take a new 'clean' picture of that area, from about the same angle and lighting.
- Create a composite in which your new shot replaces the floor and box in the old one.

I recommend a composite since you have so little floor to work with that attempting to fill in the area by cloning will not likely give you realistic results.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the best way to achieve your desired result is using "Clone tool".
Assuming you are using photoshop, please refer https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html guide.
hope this helps.